# CSS: gradients with no transitions?

Tags: css

I want to make a simple bar with two different colors. What I want is for the 1st color to stop and the second color to start with no transition or gradient. I know it sounds dumb, gradient with no gradient!

**CSS**

```
 -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 60px,rgba(27,151,143,1) 60px,rgba(27,151,143,1) 60px,rgba(27,151,143,1) 100%);
```

And it produces very close results, but where the two colors meet it gets blurry because it is still doing the transition/gradient thing.

Is there a way to do perfect stops, if that's even the term?

Comment: Check out http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ They have the style you want.

Comment: @Paulie_D [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4j35/)

Answer (score 3):

This is my favorite gradient generator tool for CSS. There is a visual editor like photoshop and it spits out the CSS for you to copy and paste.

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Jeez! That's what I used and didn't even realize that I could choose another option! Thanks for pointing that out!!!

Answer (score 0):

shortly it should be :

```
linear-gradient(
to top,
rgba(255,255,255,1) 60px,
rgba( 27,151,143,1) 60px
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b4j35/1/

and for chrome, it needs to overloap to avoid the blur defaut thingy thing :
http://jsfiddle.net/b4j35/2/

```
div.grad {
    height: 100px;
    background: linear-gradient(
to top,
rgba(255,255,255,1) 61px,
rgba( 27,151,143,1) 59px
);
    border:solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is already a *no-transition* gradient, since the end of the white and the beginning of the greenish are both at 60px. So, you can not do it better this way.

The way that is left is the multiple-background way:

```
div.grad {
    height: 100px;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, white, white), rgb(27,151,143);
    background-size: 100% 60px;
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4j35/3/)

By the way, I have changed the linear-gradient to the prefix-less version, it works like this in most modern browsers